# UIPageView horizontal swipe and vertical swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, swipe-gesture

I have the following situation:

In the storyboard I have 9 views. 3 "chapters" and each chapter has 2 "pages".

When the user swipes up or down they can switch between chapter 1, 2 and 3.
When the user gets on chapter 1, 2 or 3 and swipes left they get the pages in that chapter.

See the following image for a schematic view of the storyboard:

[image]

All these views are loaded through the pageviewcontroller.

This can be easily done with the basic swipe gestures in iOS, but we want it to scroll when you swipe.

What I have so far:

The user can swipe (scroll) between the 3 chapters throught the following code:

```
chapters = @[@"H1", @"H2", @"H3"];
UIPageViewController *pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewControllerStart"];
pageViewController.dataSource = self;

// Create all of the view controlers that display each page on the story board
viewControllers = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < chapters.count; i++) {
    start *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:chapters[i]];
    vc.index = i;
    [viewControllers addObject:vc];
}

// Set the default page to the first in the array and send it to the page view controller
NSArray *defaultViewController = [NSArray arrayWithObject:viewControllers[slideNum]];

///
pageViewController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationVertical options:nil];

pageViewController.dataSource = self;
pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 0.01);

[pageViewController setViewControllers:defaultViewController direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
///

    [self addChildViewController:pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:pageViewController.view];
    [pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

This code makes the "chapters" swipe scroll vertically perfectly.

But how can I implement the "pages" in this code so they will scroll horizontally when the user swipes left on the chapter they are?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably use a more modular storyboard, with one recycled VC for the pages, which you load multiple copies of it but assign different content. Storyboards are not meant for repeatedly laying out the same type of view.

You will want to use nested scroll views. One scroll view going up and down for the chapters that contains many scroll views scrolling left and right for the pages. You can set `-pagingEnabled` for it to page properly.